# How to convert an epoch date to joda times LocalDate?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I can see how to convert from `LocalDate` to epoch date, but how do I go the other way around?

That is, if I have the number of days from epoch, how can I construct `org.joda.time.LocalDate` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
// You'd probably make this a constant somewhere
LocalDate epoch = new LocalDate(1970, 1, 1);
LocalDate desiredDate = epoch.plusDays(daysSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: I guess this doesn't include a new dependency on the standard Java date...but it does seem awfully weird for JodaTime not to have an epoch constant somewhere. It's not the best time representation, true, but almost every language/library supports it. :P

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions: Yes, it's slightly surprising. On the other hand, it does make it crystal clear *which* epoch is in use :)

Answer (score 1):

Construct a new j[ava.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and then pass it to the [LocalDate Constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#LocalDate%28java.lang.Object%29)